# Set time zone in bash file

Tags: bash, environment-variables, timezone

I run a Matlab script `main.m` in the HPC of my university. 
To run the script I qsub in the terminal the following bash file

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=5G
#$ -l tmem=5G
#$ -l h_rt=360:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -R y
#$ -N fake1
date
hostname
/.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```

In order to fix a Matlab bug (see [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1539123)), I need to set TZ before calling Matlab. I tried to insert

```
setenv TZ America/Detroit
```

between hostname and the last line. However, it tells me command not found. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setenv` is how you set an environment variable in `csh` or `tcsh`.  In `sh` shells (`bash` being one of these), you use `export` instead:

```
date
hostname
export TZ=America/Detroit
/.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```

Or, in a more roundabout way (setting the `TZ` shell variable and then exporting it; this was how you did it in very old `sh` shells, it's usually no longer needed to do it in two steps):

```
TZ=America/Detroit
export TZ
/.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```

You may also set the `TZ` environment variable only for the `matlab` command, using either

```
TZ=America/Detroit /.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```

or

```
env TZ=America/Detroit /.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```

The `env` utility sets the given variables and executes an external command.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for that one command, then you can do:

```
TZ='America/Detroit' /.../matlabR2016b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash < main.m
```